# How to make gravity in px using node-imagemagick?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I'm trying to crop image using node-imagemagick (https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick). Can I crop from top for example on 40px and from left side also on 40px? I found option gravity how I understand it takes Center, West and so on but thats not what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `gravity` option should default to the top-left corner. If not, the option to specify this would be `NorthWest`.

```
im.crop({
  // other options
  gravity: "NorthWest"
}, function(err, stdout, stderr){
  // foo
});
```

Additionally, the package you referenced is abandoned, and suggests you should use [yourdeveloper/node-imagemagick](https://github.com/yourdeveloper/node-imagemagick) instead.